# How do I fix this output of a simple file read/write program in C?

Tags: c, file, unix

I am writing a very simple file read/write program in C. When I try to test the code, the output is not what I expect. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hwrite(FILE *fp, int count, char *str) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d ""%s", count, str);
}

void hread(FILE *fp) {
        if(fp != NULL) {
                char line [128];
                while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL) {
                        fputs(line, stdout);
                }
                fclose(fp);
        }
        else {
                perror("xxx.txt");
        }
}

int main(void) {
        int count = 1;
        char *str = "test text\n";
        FILE *fp;

        fp = fopen("xxx.txt", "a");
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                hwrite(fp, count, str);
                count = count+1;
        }
        fp = fopen("xxx.txt", "r");
        hread(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

The program compiles without issue. I then execute the a.out command once and there is no output. I do it a second time, and there is an output but it is not complete. Here:

```
[xxxxx xxx]> a.out
[xxxxx xxx]> a.out
1 test text
2 test text
3 test text
```

Then I open the file to find this:

```
1 test text
2 test text
3 test text
1 test text
2 test text
3 test text
```

Why is it not showing that in the output? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never flush the output, so it doesn't actually write to the file until your program exits.  In particular, it writes the output into the file *after* it reads the file.  Try `fclose` before you re-open for reading.

```
int main(void) {
    int count = 1;
    char *str = "test text\n";
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("xxx.txt", "a");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            hwrite(fp, count, str);
            count = count+1;
    }
    fclose(fp); /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */
    fp = fopen("xxx.txt", "r");
    hread(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying that and it compiles but when I try to run it a memory map comes up. EDIT: Never mind, I accidentally called fclose twice. It works. Thanks